# How to format SQL Strings for sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to format a string that starts out as "12.5.1" and have it be "012.005.001"  I am running this query in SQL and need it to produce these formats for sorting. Ideally if I have a value of "23.5" it would show as "023.005.000"

The reason I am doing this is for sorting in a SQL table.  Any input on how to format these values or maybe a better way to sort the values properly please let me know.

'19.99.9' must be sorted after (greater than) '2.19.99' and before (less than) '100.0.0' e.g. for software version numbering.  First formatting the strings '019.099.009', '002.019.099', '100.000.000' can achieve this.

Comment: What do these values represent?

Comment: Seems like these values should be in 3 separate `int` columns.

Comment: This is a ID field for a list of tasks that I am reporting on.  The field values are like this:

ID
1
1.1
10
10.1
10.1.1
2
2.1

I want them to sort like this:
1
1.1
2
2.1
10
10.1
10.1.1

Comment: This is a varchar field that I don't have control over.

Comment: Could you have 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1? What's the limit on decimal points?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MS SQL 2017 (or above) you have `STRING_AGG()` and `STRING_SPLIT()`

Given this table
[image: table]

Here's the simple select to get the desired format...

```
SELECT numin, LEFT(STRING_AGG(FORMAT(CAST(value AS INT),'000'), '.')+REPLICATE('.000',3),11)
FROM Table_1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(numin, '.')
GROUP BY numin
```

To put the reformatted strings into column numout...

```
UPDATE Table_1 SET numout = (
SELECT LEFT(STRING_AGG(FORMAT(CAST(value AS INT),'000'), '.') + REPLICATE('.000',3),11)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(numin, '.'))
```

`STRING_SPLIT()` creates a temp table with one column and a row per split-element
`STRING_AGG()` with `APPLY` to do the re-aggregation
and the rest is just about formatting (`REPLICATE()` for right-padding '.000', `LEFT()` to fix length)

So that...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSOurce TABLE
(
    [value] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSOurce ([value])
VALUES ('12.5.1')
      ,('23.5')
      ,('3');

SELECT *
     ,RIGHT(JSON_VALUE('["'+replace([value],'.','","')+'"]','$[0]') + 1000, 3)
     ,RIGHT(JSON_VALUE('["'+replace([value],'.','","')+'"]','$[1]') + 1000, 3)
     ,RIGHT(JSON_VALUE('["'+replace([value],'.','","')+'"]','$[2]') + 1000, 3)
     --
     ,CONCAT
      (
         RIGHT(JSON_VALUE('["'+replace([value],'.','","')+'"]','$[0]') + 1000, 3)
        ,'.'
        ,ISNULL(RIGHT(JSON_VALUE('["'+replace([value],'.','","')+'"]','$[1]') + 1000, 3), '000')
        ,'.'
        ,ISNULL(RIGHT(JSON_VALUE('["'+replace([value],'.','","')+'"]','$[2]') + 1000, 3), '000')
      )
FROM @DataSOurce
```

[image]